# Comparing Strings in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, compare

I have tried:

```
- (NSString*) generateString
{
    NSString* stringToReturn = @"thisString";
    return stringToReturn;
}

- (void) otherMethod
{
    NSString *returnedString = [self generateString];
    if (returnedString == @"thisString")
    { // Do this }
    else if (returnedString == @"thatString")
    { // Do that }
}
```

Which never matches.

I have then tried

```
if ([returnedString compare:@"thisString"] == 1)
```

But the compare method always returns 1 for me, even when comparing with a different string.

What is the correct way to do this, and what result should I expect?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

First of all, you are using the `==` operator to compare two object pointers (of type `NSString *`). So that returns true when the pointers are the same, not when the strings have the same contents. If you wanted to compare whether two strings are the same, you should use `isEqualToString:` or `isEqual:` (`isEqual:` is more general as it works for all types of objects).

Second, `compare:` returns `0` (`NSOrderSame`) when they are the same, and `1` (`NSOrderedDescending`) when the first is greater than the second. So in fact it returns 1 *only* when they are different (specifically, when the first is greater than the second).

Comment: Technically if you're comparing NSStrings you should use -isEqualToString: because that method is optimized for the case where the argument is also an NSString object.

Answer (score 12):

```
[returnedString isEqualToString: @"thisString"]
```

Answer (score 5):

When comparing two identical strings `compare` will return `NSOrderedSame`, which is 0.  It can also return `NSOrderedAscending`, -1, and `NSOrderedDescending`, 1.

You may prefer to use [`isEqualToString`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-isEqualToString_) which returns YES or NO.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ([returnedString isEqualToString:@"thisString"])
    NSLog(@"Equal");
else
    NSLog(@"Not Equal");
```

Answer (score 2):

The == operator when applied to objects check whether the pointers are equal.

You have to use `-compare` method or one of its companions -`compare:options:` -`compare:options:range:` or `-compare:options:range:locale:` which return a `NSComparisonResult` (`NSOrderAscending`, `NSOrderSame`, `NSOrderDescending`)

If you just need equality comparison, you can use `-isEqualToString:` which returns a `BOOL` value.