# iOS Compare Value of Label

Tags: ios, if-statement, uilabel

I'm using a label to display the string result of function. However I have a class variable that stores the previous result and I need to update that variable in different ways depending on different conditions. The code I wrote is

```
    if(displayPassword.text == @"Memorable")
    {
        prevpass = [newPassword returnPassword];
    }
    else 
    {
        prevpass = displayPassword.text;
    }
```

However it always jumps to the else as it seems to show under debugging that displayPassword.text is always empty depsite it showing a value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Strings in Cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881335/comparing-strings-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use `==` to compare scalar values. A string is an object. You need to use the `isEqual:` or `isEqualToString:` method instead.

```
if([displayPassword.text isEqualToString:@"Memorable"])  {
```