# Adding a basic login screen to a Mac application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsstring, nstextfield

I'm really new to Mac application building and I'm trying out some different techniques. I'm trying to figure out how to put in a basic login (username and password) screen into my app. In my method I currently have this, attempting to use the if else statements (the set background colour is just a temp replacement for opening the next window).

```
- (IBAction)loginb:(id)sender {
if (m_username == [@"haseo98" NSString]){
    [_window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
}
 else [_window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
}
```

The main problem in my opinion is with this line:

```
 if (m_username == [@"haseo98" NSString]){
```

How do I get XCode to read what's in the NSTextfield and compare it to "haseo98"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTextField` is a `NSControl`, so you can use [`-stringValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000073-BAJEBFBE) to get the text content:

```
NSString *name = [usernameTextfield stringValue];
```

To compare the strings, use [`-isEqualToString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-isEqualToString_):

```
if ([name isEqualToString:@"haseo98"]){
```

Note that comparing strings using `==` [doesn't usually do what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881377/168225) and that string literals (`@"text"`) are already `NSString` instances.