# can't perform logic NSString *

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing Strings in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881335/comparing-strings-in-cocoa)

I need to perform logic on an `NSString*` variable.

If I do the following it works fine:

```
my_label_3.text = local_db_user.lifetime_subscription;
```

The label in the UI gets populated with the text, `True`

But the following returns `NO`:

```
local_db_user.lifetime_subscription == @"True"
```

What code do I use for this pseudo code:

```
if local_db_user.lifetime_subscription == True
    do this
else
    do this other thing
```

My watch, during debugging, on `local_db_user.lifetime_subscription` shows:

```
{NSString * | 0x764e210} "True"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use isEqualToString: to compare between to NSString objects.

As the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) points out:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString
```

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given string is equal
>   to the receiver using a literal Unicode-based comparison.

so to answer your question, your code should look like:

```
if ([local_db_user.lifetime_subscription isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
    // is equal
}
else {
    // is different
}
```

Comment: Thanks all. I see that people found this to be an exact duplicate. Well I hope it remains visible, because, after a lot of searching, I never found my answer in stack. - which I love. :-) Again thanks.

Comment: Hey @pdschuller, your welcome! As you can see, we are happy to help! Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

```
if([local_db_user.lifetime_subscription isEqualToString:@"True"])
 {
        //do the task here
 }
 else
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing object using equal operator(==) it's check for memory address.
so compare the NSString object you have to use

- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString;

method.
for your own (custom class) objects have to override below method.

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject